# Filter Multiple Lists for Element

Tags: python, list, filter

I have 2 lists containing JSON values, `allBuilds` and `rawRequirements`. Each list has a length of 1201 items.

The contents of `allBuilds` looks like this:

```
{'id': 19553, 'buildTypeId': 'AlpsWeb_AlpsWebDeployWebDev'}
{'id': 24456, 'buildTypeId': 'AlpsWeb_AlpsWebDeployWebDevTomcat8', }
None
None
{'id': 19356, 'buildTypeId': 'AlpsWeb_AlpsWebDeployWebQa',}
{'id': 19357, 'buildTypeId': 'AlpsWeb_AlpsWebDeployWebQa',}
None
{'id': 19357, 'buildTypeId': 'AlpsWeb_AlpsWebDeployWebQa',}
```

I need to filter the contents of `allBuilds` to remove `None` while also removing the corresponding element from `rawRequirements`. I tried

```
successfulBuilds = list(filter(None, allBuilds))
```

This removes `None` but now the length of the new list `successfulBuilds` is 972 while `rawRequirements` is still 1201.

How can I filter `allBuilds` for `None` and also remove the corresponding list element in `rawRequirements`?

---- EDIT ----

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
allBuilds |  rawRequirements
id        |  Requirement value1
none      |  Requirement value2 <-- 
none      |  Requirement value3 <-- 
id        |  Requirement value4
none      |  Requirement value5 <-- 
id        |  Requirement value6
```

I need to remove the element in rawRequirements at the same column where "none" exists in allBuilds

Comment: can you share how both list are related an example ?

Comment: @temmo I've updated my question with an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
allBuilds, rawRequirements = zip(*((ab, rR) for ab, rR in zip(allBuilds, rawRequirements) if ab is not None))
```

`zip` takes some getting used to but it is very efficient for filtering or sorting multiple lists.

Comment: @temmo 1 shot is all you need here :)

Comment: i prefer going through Hyperbolic Time Chamber way XD

Comment: @temmo my answer is basically a step by step version of this one.

Comment: @STreu i saw that, here we are just doing some otaku thing

Comment: I remember you, @jojo! you've answered my question about the face- and edgecolors! =)

Comment: @temmo what is otaku?

Comment: @STreu ha, yes I remember that!

Comment: @STreu Otaku is a Japanese term for people with obsessive interests, particularly in anime and manga [google said this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=otaku)

Comment: @temmo tanks for explaining! so in this case it is about python in general or the one shot solution?

Comment: just for python one also 'one punch man' is anime, so use it's reference for this here

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
a=[1,2,3,None,4,5,6,7,None,10]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

new_a =[]
new_b =[]

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v is not None:
        new_a.append(v)
        new_b.append(b[i])

print(new_a,new_b,sep='\n')
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10] #a
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9] #b
```

Comment: self explaining solution +1 from my side!

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip:

```py
zipped =  zip(allBuilds,rawRequirements)
filtered_zip =  ((el1, el2) for ab, rR in zipped if el1 != None))
filtered_allBuilds, filteredRequirements = zip(*filtered_zip)
```

Comment: but this is easier to grasp. Just in case: a linter might complain about the `el1 != None` the recommended way is `el1 is not None` ;)